# Updating `this` in a extension on a typdef

Tags: dart

I have this code:

```
typedef Something = int;

extension SomethingExt on Something {
  void reset() {
    this = 0; // This causes a error
  }
}
```

But I get `Illegal assignment to non-assignable expression.dart(illegal_assignment_to_non_assignable)`

Is it possible to update the value of the typedef in the extension?

My use case, is I have many `Something`, and right now it's a `class Something { int _value; }`, and it feels wasteful to have a object to hold a int, I'd rather just use the int directly.

Comment: You cannot update "this".  A method extension can execute methods against "this", but not actually replace "this" as an object.  No method in dart can do that!

Comment: The very short reason is: `this` is not a *variable*. Even if it was, it would be a `final` variable. So you can't assign to the name `this`. It's just a way to refer to a value.

Comment: The typedef does nothing here, it does not introduce a new type, just a new name for the same type, so this is just `extension SomethingExt on int { ... }` with more words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not only specific to typedefs and extensions, but in fact, you can't re-assign an object with `this`. See this example:

```dart
class Something {
  Something(this.anInt, this.aString);

  int anInt;
  String aString;

  void resetMe() {
    this.anInt = 0; // You can do this, 'anInt' is a member of 'this'
    this.aString = ''; // You can do this, 'aString' is a member of 'this'
    this = Something(0, ''); // You CAN'T do this, 'this' is the object itself
  }
}
```

(Note: I explicitly use `this` to access members to show the difference)